# Claim that we shouldn't give homeless people money because they will "spend it on drugs/alcohol"?

Tags: ethics

Every time that I run into a homeless person, which is frequently, I give them whatever change or spare bills (almost always $1 but occasionally, $5 or $10) that I have on me because I believe that a homeless person will always need money more than I do.  I have an apartment, I have food, I have heat, I have clothes, they have none of this.

So, my question:  Is there any philosophical basis to the argument that we should not give money to homeless people because "they will just use it on drugs and alcohol"? What justifications are there that say that my prerogative to spend money how I want to is any "better" than the prerogative of the homeless person?

Comment: Not very "philosophical", but if I ever found myself homeless, I would like to think I could count on the generosity of others on an informal, non-institutional basis. So I give to street people. It could be me one day.

Comment: We give various tax subsidies to wealthy people (Elon Musk for example) and many of those people use drugs and alcohol (Elon Musk for example). What's the difference?

Answer (score 5):

Were I to argue against you, I'd pick up a utilitarian stance.  As a person and as a citizen, it is your responsibility to minimize suffering.

Of the ways you can affect the homeless through spare change, is giving the homeless money directly the optimal way to minimize their suffering?  I'd argue not.

There is hardly an effective way to know whether or not the person is actually homeless; they could just be scamming--in which case, you're not minimizing the suffering of the homeless.  Even if they are homeless, are you able to minimize more suffering by donating to them directly or by donating to a charity that helps the homeless?  That's case by case, depending on the homeless person and the charity, but my suspicion is that charities have the infrastructure necessary to help more of the homeless you encounter.

So by that reasoning, giving money directly to the homeless is a failure to act properly because you are not minimizing suffering in the most optimal way.

edit: okay, so maybe I ignored the "they'll just spend it on drugs" argument.  I think it's a weak argument to make against giving people money because it relies on not knowing.  In order to really get at the meat of the issue, you have to assume either they will or won't, and then sort out both possibilities.

Comment: People should also keep in mind that it's not just a choice between giving money to a homeless individual and giving money to a charity. If you want to give a homeless person money for food, for example, go into the restaurant/store with them and buy them a piece of food. This is probably the best way to go about these things, though it does require a bit more of a time commitment and will require you to actually interact with the homeless person, which some people find to be an uncomfortable trade-off when compared to just tossing a dollar bill at them and walking away.

Comment: ^^ The above also has the added advantage that you will quickly sort fraudsters from people genuinely begging for their food money. Offer to buy someone a sandwich from 7-11 when they ask you for money. If they backpedal or otherwise make a fuss about getting the cash, you know they're going to use it on something other than food in which case you can deny giving the money and reinforce your offer to buy them food. If they deny twice you walk away.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen a few approaches (not necessarily agreeing or disagreeing, just saying that they are there):

1. A deontological (duty-oriented) approach would say "using drugs and alcohol is bad for you, and so giving money to poor people for them to use drugs and alcohol makes you an enabler."
2. One reasoning is: well, we have homeless shelters, and giving the homeless money allows them to continue living on the streets instead of the shelters where they are better off (and where meals can be provided more cheaply). I've heard this both from a utilitarian point of view (it's better for everyone if they just go to the homeless shelter), but also from some who look it as a "tough-love" sort of approach (as if not giving to someone is doing that person a favor).

Comment: If that's true, then it's immoral to pay taxes, since DEA agents used hookers supplied by the drug cartels. You agree? http://news.yahoo.com/u-dea-agents-had-sex-parties-funded-drug-160828541.html Why is it that everyone has such high moral standards for homeless people, but doesn't apply the same standards of waste, fraud, and abuse to the taxes they pay (under threat of imprisonment) to the government?

Comment: To me, that seems immoral several times over, but seems like a different question than was asked above.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to stay on subject that giving money to homeless people - or panhandlers or those who "fly a sign" to get money -- as being wrong I would say is wrong by merit that you assume all people who are homeless or panhandleing are drug users. You are assuming they are on the streets because their use of drugs made them homeless. Which along that train of thought homeless people are homeless because they are addicts... This I know is not 100% correct. While there may be many homeless addicts, the ones able to swallow their pride enough to beg for money I do not believe are.  I know first hand because I once was an office manager of a day labor place and when I could not send these three guys out on job one day, I found them on the corner flying signs. I asked them the next day why and was told it took all three of them doing that to get enough money to pay for a hotel room for the night. It was winter and very cold. I made sure they got a work order that day. And I know from other people that came to the temp hall, that staying in a shelter is not all that great. They told me the shelter's literally kick them out early in the morning and don't let them back in until late afternoon. Then once they do check in, after I think 7p.m., they must stay in the shelter and are not allowed even to go outside to smoke a cigarette or else will be permanently out for the entire night.  Additionally, there is a high rate of thievery in the shelters and chances are high that when you do go to sleep what little possessions you have will not be there when you wake up. Granted a growing majority of those taking handouts are scammers, and drive better cars than I do, but some really are in great need.  Bottom line, it really should not matter whether or not the person receiving your gift is honestly in need.  Look to yourself for the reasons to give.  You are giving from your heart because you believe you have more than that person and desire to share your good fortune in hopes of aiding someone less fortunate.  Also: "There but for the Grace of God, go I." That and for me it's a little of "Do not forget to entertain strangers, for by so doing some have unwittingly entertained angels." Heb. 13:2.... I recommend doing what you feel is best, because if society as a whole were truly concerned enough about the growing homeless situation, it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE! Perhaps you could consider using **paragraphs** and **references** (preferably to philosophers) to your answer to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

While giving money to homeless people is kind it is not the best why do donate money, not even for them. It is bad in the same why the socialism is. In soviet Russia people had no reason to try at anything as all our actions even giving people money are to make our lives better. Even giving people money makes us feel better and could be considered a selfish act, arguably. Yet money is the main tangible thing that is used to improve our lives, and for the Russians they did not have control over this thus they did as little as they could to get by and Russian businesses had horrible service and parts would normally come malfunctioning if they came at all. However there was a solution, of sorts, America tried freedom and capitalism that made us soon grow to be one of the largest best producing nations in the world. That was because when Americans worked harder they got paid more, so Americans worked harder not only benefitting them but also everyone around them and that worked because people hat reason to work harder so they did.
      However I am not saying to abandon and lose hope on all the homeless population, some which albeit have mental problems keeping them this way l. What I am saying is that it would be much more useful and helpful to find a way to perminently get them of the street not give them some money which in the end won't mean much.

Give a man a fish feed you feed him for a day, teach a man to fish you feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: If you have any references to those who take a similar position this would give the reader a place to go for more information and strengthen the answer. Welcome.